# PHP: strtr() memory exhausted

Tags: php, out-of-memory, php-8.1, strtr

I have a function that checks and decodes the content from various variables:

```
public static function decode($content, $flag=ENT_NOQUOTES){
    if ( !empty($content) && is_string($content) && !is_numeric($content) && !is_array($content) && !is_object($content) ) {
        if (filter_var($content, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            $content = rawurldecode($content);
        } else {
            $content = htmlspecialchars_decode($content, $flag);
            $content = html_entity_decode($content, $flag);
            $content = strtr($content, array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, $flag)));
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

In some cases with some clients I run into a memory problem where the `strtr()` function consumes all the memory.

The problem is I can't figure out why.

Comment: What's the size of your data set? Are you exhausting the whole system memory or just the maximum amount allowed for this particular script?

Comment: FYI: Applying `htmlspecialchars_decode` _and_ `html_entity_decode` is superfluous - the latter covers everything the former does already.

Comment: I use both 256MB and 512MB, once I set it to 1GB, but it used that too. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Can you explain what the actual point of what you are doing there is supposed to be? You are flipping the array that `get_html_translation_table` returns, meaning you will have an array `['&quot;' => '"', '&amp;' => '&', ...]`, so that this `strtr` call would now replace those entities with their actual corresponding characters. But hey, hold on - _what_ entities? You applied `html_entity_decode` already, so which entities are supposed to actually be left in $content at this point ...?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Data size is crucial because it's what determines the memory needed. I've done some quick benchmarking and I need around 200 million characters to get past 512 MiB. If you're manipulating strings that size, you'll possibly need to split input in chunks. If you are not, you just have a leak somewhere else (this code does lots of redundant stuff, as already pointed out, but it can't possible have an infinite loop or anything like that).